# How to Send Angular 6 POST Values to Codeigniter function?

Tags: php, angular, angular6, codeigniter-3

Here is the

> **registration.component.ts**

registrationDetails(event) {

> ```
> const target = event.target;
> const app_key = 'a9a4a7757d840aa317bb585f4acbdf0d';
> const first_name = target.querySelector("#firstname").value;
> const last_name = target.querySelector("#lastname").value;
> const email = target.querySelector("#username").value;
> const password = target.querySelector("#password").value;
> const phone = target.querySelector("#phone_number").value;
> this.Auth.postRegistration(first_name, last_name, email, password,phone,app_key).subscribe(
>   data => {
>     if ((data.status == 1)) {
>       this.toastr.success('Registartion Successfull, Please login', "Thank you..!");
>     } else {
>       this.toastr.error(data.response, "OOPS..!");
>     }
>   }
> );   }
> ```

and Here is the

> **auth.service.ts**

```
postRegistration(first_name, last_name, email, password,phone,app_key) {
    return this.Http.post<objects>(`${this.baseUrl}/user/registerUser`, {
      first_name,
      last_name,
      email,
      phone,
      password,
      app_key
    });
```

when am running this file the posting values are not going to Codeigniter function 
what is the problem in this and what are changes should be done,
actually core php works **$_POST['email']** but **$this->input->post('email')** this is not working why ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here you are passing raw data

so try this

```
postRegistration(first_name, last_name, email, password,phone,app_key) {
    const header = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
    let body = 'first_name='+first_name+'&last_name='+last_name+'&email='+email+'&phone='+phone+'&password='+password+'&app_key='+app_key;
    return this.Http.post<objects>(`${this.baseUrl}/user/registerUser`, body, {headers: header});
}
```

Comment: No I need values from angular as post values to Codeigniter, Not like Json Object values, I need Values are should be POST Values from angular

Comment: Great Boss..! Awesome its works Thank you you made my day..!